# Calculating sin(x) w/oMath and using loops only in java

Tags: java, loops, trigonometry

I've got to calculate Math.sin(x) using the Taylor Series:

> n
>
> ∑ (-1)^i* (x^(2i+1) / (2i+1)!) for n → ∞
>
> i=0

Therefore, I am only allowed to use loops (no recursion) and I may not use the Math class. 
This is how far I've come:

```
public double sinLoops(double x) {
        int potenz1;
        double potenz2 = x;
        double fac = 1;
        double result = 0;

        do {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                potenz1 = 1;
            } else {
                potenz1 = (-1);
            }

            for (int counter = 1; counter < (2 * i + 1); counter++) {
                potenz2 *= x;
            }
            for (int counter2 = (2 * i + 1); counter2 >= 1; counter2--) {
                fac *= counter2;
            }   
            result += potenz1 * potenz2 / fac;
            i++;
        } while (result > 0.0000001 || result < -0.0000001);
        return result;
    }
```

However, I think my break condition isn't quite correct (-1*10^-7 or 1*10^-7),the returned result is NaN. 
I've already looked it up, but I am kinda overchallenged right now, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an endless loop because your while condition isn't what you want it to be. You are probably trying to reuse variables for 2 different purposes and failing. Create a delta variable where you store the change made in this interation and test the detla value in the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You did not initialize i.
2. You checked the final conditional against result rather than that taylor element of the sum.
3. You left the potenz2 and fac elements to keep spiral out of control rather than reset them for each new element in the series.
4. Eventually they would reach infinity and infinity, divide those and get NaN. NaN added to the running result is NaN and that actually returns true for the conditional and exited the loop (NaN has odd effects with conditionals).

Here's the working code with comments at the problems.

```
    public double sinLoops(double x) {
        int i = 0; //this didn't exist.
        double result = 0;
        double seriesElement; //You need the individual taylor series element.
        do {
            double potenz2 = x; //these need to be reset each time.
            double fac = 1; //if not they overflow and infinity/infinity is NaN and it exits.
            int potenz1 = ((i & 1) == 1) ? -1 : 1; //this is just short hand.
            for (int counter = 1; counter < (2 * i + 1); counter++) {
                potenz2 *= x;
            }
            for (int counter2 = (2 * i + 1); counter2 >= 1; counter2--) {
                fac *= counter2; //we could actually keep the last iteration and do 2*(i-1)+1 to 2*i+1 each new i.
            }
            seriesElement = potenz1 * potenz2 / fac; //we need to save the value here.

            result += seriesElement; //we are summing them in the results.
            i++;

        } while (seriesElement > 0.0000001 || seriesElement < -0.0000001); //We check this conditional against the series element, *NOT THE RESULT*
        return result;
    }
```

In case anybody needs this somehow for some kind of production work with speed being critical (and a less wrong answer, though really in that case use Math), rather than the "can somebody do my homework for me" type here's the optimized code:

```
public double sinLoops(double x) {
        double result = 0, powerx = -1, fac = 1;
        int i = 0, n, m = 0;
        while (true) {
            n = m;
            m = (i++*2) + 1;
            powerx *= -1;
            while (n < m) {
                powerx *= x;
                fac *= ++n;
            }
            if ((Double.isInfinite(fac)) || (Double.isInfinite(powerx))) break;
            result += powerx / fac;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't do any of the obvious improvements like using one counter loop rather than 2 (hint: you're looping the same number of times!), or do the obvious improvement maintaining values for potenz2 and fac and just looping the additional i times in a single loop, which also would allow you to get rid of potenz1 nonsense and just multiply the sum by -1 each time (it would cycle correctly).

Comment: And fixed the parity issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying the value of result variable :)

Also variable i is undeclared.
Really, would be much easier if you posted a working code sample.

Once that is fixed, you should be comparing the change between previous calculation and the latest to your delta value (0.000001), not result itself.  Your loop needs to end once series converges to the desired precision, not when the calculated value is really small.

You also have a couple of mistakes like off-by-one error in loop counters and not re-initializing accumulating variables between loop iterations.  It is easily analyzed by running through the case of arguments of 0 and Pi.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry :D The variable "ergebnis" is the variable "result", I will change that directly - it was a spelling mistake I made while translating all the variables from German to English :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.
Like Tatarize, I hope this ain't homework avoidance.

This code looks to presage the number of terms needed to give an absolute precision of +/- 0.000 000 1 in the result for all angles 0 - 90 degrees.

The highest power term makes a difference of x^k / k! to the result.
So

```
            x^k / k!  < 1 / 10^7
```

Here x is in radians so the biggest value of x ~ 1.57 rads.
This means that only a series up to power 13 will give you a final term less than 0.000 000 1 .

Unfortunately my PC is of advanced age (32-bit) and any attempt to compute 13! causes overflow. So I adapt the [Horner method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49051/using-horners-method) a bit, maybe losing some efficiency but avoiding factorial overflow and allowing a halt if the angle is small or if adequate precision is gained before power 13.

```
  Sin x = x - x^2(x/3! - x^2(x/5! - x^2(x/7! - . . . - x^2(x/(m-1)!- x^2(x/m!)
```

where m is the highest power needed for the desired absolute precision.

```
  Sin x = x + Sum { iTerm(i) * x^2 / (i * (i-1)) }
```

where

```
  iTerm(0) = x and iTerm(n) = - x^2 * iTerm(n-1)/(i*(i-1)
```

PS - Why can't we use Math formatting outside the Mathematics Stack Exchange ?
It would make writing equations so much clearer.

```
public class TrigByPoly
{
    // No constructor used.

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double x0 = 0, 
               x1 = Math.PI/12, 
               x2 = Math.PI/6,  
               x3 = Math.PI/4,
               x4 = Math.PI/3,
               x5 = Math.PI/2;

        double sinx0 = SinByPoly(x0),
               sinx1 = SinByPoly(x1),
               sinx2 = SinByPoly(x2),
               sinx3 = SinByPoly(x3),
               sinx4 = SinByPoly(x4),
               sinx5 = SinByPoly(x5); 

        System.out.println("Sin(0) to 7 decimal places is : " + sinx0);
        System.out.println("Sin(15) to 7 decimal places is : " + sinx1);
        System.out.println("Sin(30) to 7 decimal places is : " + sinx2);
        System.out.println("Sin(45) to 7 decimal places is : " + sinx3);
        System.out.println("Sin(60) to 7 decimal places is : " + sinx4);
        System.out.println("Sin(90) to 7 decimal places is : " + sinx5);
    }

    public static double SinByPoly(double x)
    {
        int i = 0;  // Polynomial order indicator.

        double x2 = x * x,
               iTerm,   
               sinx = 0;

        if (x < 0.0084) // Limiting angle for Sinx = x to 10^-7 precision.
            sinx = x;
        else
        {
            sinx = x;
            iTerm = sinx;
            i = 3;
            do
            {
                iTerm = - x2 * iTerm / ( i * (i - 1));
                sinx += iTerm;
                i = i + 2;
            } while (i < 14 && (iTerm > 0.0000001 || -iTerm > 0.0000001));
        }
        return sinx;
    }
}

OUTPUT
======

Sin(0) to an absolute precision of 1.0E-7 is : 0.0
Sin(15) to an absolute precision of 1.0E-7 is : 0.2588190618109834
Sin(30) to an absolute precision of 1.0E-7 is : 0.4999999918690232
Sin(45) to an absolute precision of 1.0E-7 is : 0.7071067829368671
Sin(60) to an absolute precision of 1.0E-7 is : 0.8660254450997811
Sin(75) to an absolute precision of 1.0E-7 is : 0.9659258210120795
Sin(90) to an absolute precision of 1.0E-7 is : 0.999999943741051
```

Comment: I've started using Latex on the web here and there to get a graphics file an imbedding it for that stupid can't do math equations.

Comment: The StackOverflow DBA says here [link]http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on it's going to slow loading ALL SO pages if it's added. But maybe there is some way of dynamically including it or a lighter version of it . . .?